# Create a nested array of comments

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently creating a little WordPress-import-script using `PHP`.

This is a part of my XML input:

```
    <wp:comment>
        <wp:comment_id>1</wp:comment_id>
        <wp:comment_author><![CDATA[this-is-a-test]]></wp:comment_author>
        <wp:comment_author_email>test@example.org</wp:comment_author_email>
        <wp:comment_author_url>http://this-is-a-test.wordpress.com</wp:comment_author_url>
        <wp:comment_author_IP>134.76.4.169</wp:comment_author_IP>
        <wp:comment_date>2017-12-21 11:23:31</wp:comment_date>
        <wp:comment_date_gmt>2017-12-21 09:23:31</wp:comment_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_content><![CDATA[Test-Comment]]></wp:comment_content>
        <wp:comment_approved>1</wp:comment_approved>
        <wp:comment_type></wp:comment_type>
        <wp:comment_parent>0</wp:comment_parent>
        <wp:comment_user_id>132023990</wp:comment_user_id>
    </wp:comment>
    <wp:comment>
        <wp:comment_id>2</wp:comment_id>
        <wp:comment_author><![CDATA[this-is-a-test]]></wp:comment_author>
        <wp:comment_author_email>test@example.org</wp:comment_author_email>
        <wp:comment_author_url>http://this-is-a-test.wordpress.com</wp:comment_author_url>
        <wp:comment_author_IP>134.76.4.169</wp:comment_author_IP>
        <wp:comment_date>2017-12-21 11:25:49</wp:comment_date>
        <wp:comment_date_gmt>2017-12-21 09:25:49</wp:comment_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_content><![CDATA[Answering a comment]]></wp:comment_content>
        <wp:comment_approved>1</wp:comment_approved>
        <wp:comment_type></wp:comment_type>
        <wp:comment_parent>1</wp:comment_parent>
        <wp:comment_user_id>132023990</wp:comment_user_id>
    </wp:comment>
    <wp:comment>
        <wp:comment_id>3</wp:comment_id>
        <wp:comment_author><![CDATA[this-is-a-test]]></wp:comment_author>
        <wp:comment_author_email>test@example.org</wp:comment_author_email>
        <wp:comment_author_url>http://this-is-a-test.wordpress.com</wp:comment_author_url>
        <wp:comment_author_IP>134.76.4.169</wp:comment_author_IP>
        <wp:comment_date>2017-12-21 11:26:12</wp:comment_date>
        <wp:comment_date_gmt>2017-12-21 09:26:12</wp:comment_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_content><![CDATA[Another comment.]]></wp:comment_content>
        <wp:comment_approved>1</wp:comment_approved>
        <wp:comment_type></wp:comment_type>
        <wp:comment_parent>0</wp:comment_parent>
        <wp:comment_user_id>132023990</wp:comment_user_id>
    </wp:comment>
```

I created a little script, that iterates through all comments and adds them to the post (`array`) they belong to.

At the moment the array of comments is "flat" just like that:

```
  ["comments"]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    object(WPComment)#835 (8) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["author"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email"]=>
      string(23) "me@example.org"
      ["url"]=>
      string(32) "http://example.wordpress.com"
      ["ip"]=>
      string(12) "123.123.123.123"
      ["content"]=>
      string(18) "Test comment"
      ["created"]=>
      object(DateTime)#836 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2017-12-21 11:23:31.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(3) "UTC"
      }
      ["status"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [2]=>
    object(WPComment)#834 (8) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(2)
      ["author"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email"]=>
      string(23) "me@example.org"
      ["url"]=>
      string(32) "http://example.wordpress.com"
      ["ip"]=>
      string(12) "123.123.123.123"
      ["content"]=>
      string(41) "Answering a test-comment"
      ["created"]=>
      object(DateTime)#838 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2017-12-21 11:25:49.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(3) "UTC"
      }
      ["status"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [3]=>
    object(WPComment)#837 (8) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(3)
      ["author"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email"]=>
      string(23) "me@example.org"
      ["url"]=>
      string(32) "http://example.wordpress.com"
      ["ip"]=>
      string(12) "123.123.123.123"
      ["content"]=>
      string(36) "And even another test-comment."
      ["created"]=>
      object(DateTime)#840 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2017-12-21 11:26:12.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(3) "UTC"
      }
      ["status"]=>
      int(1)
    }
```

And this is how I created the array:

```
foreach ($blog_post->comment as $comment) {
    switch ($comment->comment_approved) {
        case '1' :
            $comment_status = Comment::STATUS_APPROVED;
            break;
        case '0' :
            $comment_status = Comment::STATUS_PENDING;
            break;
        case 'spam' :
            $comment_status = Comment::STATUS_SPAM;
            break;
        default :
            $comment_status = Comment::STATUS_PENDING;
    }

    $wp_c                                = new WPComment;
    $comments[(int)$comment->comment_id] = $wp_c->create([
        'id'      => (int)$comment->comment_id,
        'author'  => (string)$comment->comment->author,
        'email'   => (string)$comment->comment_author_email,
        'url'     => (string)$comment->comment_author_url,
        'ip'      => (string)$comment->comment_author_IP,
        'created' => new \DateTime($comment->comment_date),
        'content' => (string)$comment->comment_content,
        'status'  => $comment_status,
    ]);

    //ksort($comments);

}
```

Alright - now I would like to create a nested array - each child-comment should be added to his parent.

The expected result should be:

```
  ["comments"]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    object(WPComment)#835 (8) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["author"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email"]=>
      string(23) "me@example.org"
      ["url"]=>
      string(32) "http://example.wordpress.com"
      ["ip"]=>
      string(12) "123.123.123.123"
      ["content"]=>
      string(18) "Test comment"
      ["created"]=>
      object(DateTime)#836 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2017-12-21 11:23:31.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(3) "UTC"
      }
      ["status"]=>
      int(1)
      ["children"] =>     [1]=>
        object(WPComment)#834 (8) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(2)
          ["author"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["email"]=>
          string(23) "me@example.org"
          ["url"]=>
          string(32) "http://example.wordpress.com"
          ["ip"]=>
          string(12) "123.123.123.123"
          ["content"]=>
          string(41) "Answering a test-comment"
          ["created"]=>
          object(DateTime)#838 (3) {
            ["date"]=>
            string(26) "2017-12-21 11:25:49.000000"
            ["timezone_type"]=>
            int(3)
            ["timezone"]=>
            string(3) "UTC"
          }
          ["status"]=>
          int(1)
        }
    }
    [3]=>
    object(WPComment)#837 (8) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(3)
      ["author"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email"]=>
      string(23) "me@example.org"
      ["url"]=>
      string(32) "http://example.wordpress.com"
      ["ip"]=>
      string(12) "123.123.123.123"
      ["content"]=>
      string(36) "And even another test-comment."
      ["created"]=>
      object(DateTime)#840 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2017-12-21 11:26:12.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(3) "UTC"
      }
      ["status"]=>
      int(1)
    }
```

The best possible solution would be that even the children could have children.

I'd love to hear your suggestions on how to do this the most elegant and readable way :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not something like: In the loop -> If it has `$comment->comment_parent` dont add it as array element add it to `arrayX[$comment->comment_parent].children` ...

Comment: Unfortunately this is no option, as this does only work with one additional dimension.

But it could also be:
```
- Comment
 - Has child
  - has child
```
So it would be `$array[$x][$y]` - but we can not know how much dimensions this has.

Comment: Still possible if we create an endless loop inside, which stops as soon as the parent has no more parent. Inside the loops has to be build up either a reference of the grandparent or a variable.